# Disable two-factor when I don't have an iPhone anymore

Tags: messages, two-step-authentication, two-factor-authentication

Until recently, I was using iMessage on both iOS and macOS. Now, my phone is dead with a black screen, so I did a full erase from iTunes. ("Find my iPhone" and iCloud is disabled on both devices.)

Currently, I am still able to use iMessage from macOS. My iMessage account is connected only to my phone number, not my email address, and I'd like to keep it that way.

My Mac and iPhone has two-factor setup, so you confirm stuff with the other device other. Since I now don't have an iPhone, how do I disable two-factor **without** breaking iMessage or anything?

Answer (score 4):

[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915) addresses this very scenario:

> #### What if I don’t have access to a trusted device or didn't receive a verification code?
>
> If you're signing in and don’t have a trusted device handy that can
> display verification codes, you can have a code sent to your trusted
> phone number via text message or an automated phone call instead.
> Click Didn't Get a Code on the sign in screen and choose to send a
> code to your trusted phone number. You can also get a code directly
> from Settings on a trusted device. Learn how to get a [verification
> code](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204974).

If you trusted device is your iPhone and you say that it's connected to your phone number, this is a good thing.  What you will need is a (cheap) replacement phone that can receive calls/SMS (text messages).  Depending on your carrier (i.e AT&T or TMobile) you can just move your SIM card to another phone to receive the call/text message with the verification code.  If it's a carrier that doesn't use SIM cards (Verizon, Sprint), you will have to get them to activate the cheap phone for you.

Once you get the call/SMS, you can now validate your account to disable two-factor authentication.

If all else fails, you still have another option...

> #### If you still can't sign in
>
> If you can’t sign in, reset your password, or receive verification
> codes, you can [request account recovery to regain access to your
> account](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204921). Account recovery might take a few days or longer, depending
> on the specific account information you can provide to verify your
> identity.

Answer (score 2):

At this writing it is *not possible* to disable two factor authentication if it has been enabled and two weeks have lapsed. I just ended a chat with Apple support seeking to do this, and was informed of this (but that it really is the best security option).

https://www.apple.com/feedback/

I never needed the option, it was a mistake to switch it on, and now I can't switch it off.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try logging into [iCloud](http://www.icloud.com) and disable 2FA there, in the settings. Use Chrome to avoid Apple's integrations in Safari. You will need your Mac to approve the login of Chrome.