# Can't sign into my Apple ID because of two step authentication

Tags: apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I need to sign into my apple ID account but I have two-factor authentication turned on and don't know the phone number I used for that Apple ID account as someone else created it for me.

I have only one Apple device on which I've signed out of iCloud I still know my iCloud password it's just the phone number I don't know. Is there any way to access my account without this phone number?

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304953/119271  There's information about gaining access if you don't have access to your phone number and/or trusted device.

Comment: I don’t know the trusted number.

Comment: There is a link at the *end* of the answer.

Comment: I followed it but it asked me for the trusted phone number which I don’.to know.

Comment: You could try calling Apple Support to get the issue resolved.