# How to recover Apple account login when 2-step authentication without Apple device?

Tags: apple-id, password, two-step-authentication

I remember my Apple ID and password but not security questions so I cannot recover my account, since I do not have my iPad and not my iPhone anymore.

I processed Apple iForgot many times but they do not offer recovery by phone number.

My older devices: iPad mini and iPhone 4S, which I do not anymore have. I do not remember if my account has my phone number, at least, the iForgot does not try to send me an SMS.

Comment: for what Apple device do you need Apple ID since you do not have any anymore ? `My older devices: iPad mini and iPhone 4S, which I do not anymore have.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable two-factor when I don't have an iPhone anymore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281516/disable-two-factor-when-i-dont-have-an-iphone-anymore)

Comment: @Allan That question is about two-factor, not two-step.

Comment: @grg - Same thing.

Comment: @Allan Nope, see my last paragraph in my answer. One has account recovery, the other does not. They are extremely different but [often confused](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3416/rename-two-step-authentication-to-two-step-verification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On setting up two-step verification, a recovery key is provided. This recovery key helps you regain access to your account.

If you have lost both your trusted devices and your recovery key to an account secured with two-step verification, you are unable to regain access to the account.

> If you've permanently lost any two of these items, you can't sign in or regain access to your account. You'll need to create a new Apple ID.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202649

Unlike two-step verification, [two-factor-authentication](/questions/tagged/two-factor-authentication) does have a separate account recovery process, but this is only possible for accounts migrated to or otherwise protected with two-factor authentication instead of two-step verification.